# Remove multiple postings but keep first

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have a table which has had numerous postings over the course of the week that I need to remove, the timestamp is different so i need to keep the first entry but then remove all the others which came after that.

What techniques would be advised.

SQL Server 2008

Many thanks
J

Comment: You should tag your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE with `delete`.  The result is something like this:

```
with todelete as (
      select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by post_id order by datetimecol asc) as seqnum
      from posts p
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

You can just run the subquery to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the posts except the oldest

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    select top 1 id 
    from tbl
    order by TimeStampColumn
)
```